# How run mahout in action example ReutersToSparseVectors?

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I want run "ReutersToSparseVectors.java". I can compile and created JAR file without problem.

I compiled this file by below command:

`javac -classpath hadoop-core-0.20.205.0.jar:lucene-core-3.6.0.jar:mahout-core-0.7.jar:mahout-math-0.7.jar ReutersToSparseVectors.java`

created JAR file with below command:

`jar cvf ReutersToSparseVectors.jar ReutersToSparseVectors.class`

When I write java -jar ReutersToSparseVectors.jar to run, give me below error:

Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
ReutersToSparseVectors.jar

Do you can help me to solve this problem?

IF this example can run with hadoop, please me that how i can run this with hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `-jar` option, then it's better to to run:

```
 java -cp mahout-core.jar:... mia.clustering.ch09.ReutersToSparseVectors
```

or you can use `mvn exec:java` command, as [described in README](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA) for examples...

```
 mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="mia.clustering.ch09.ReutersToSparseVectors"
```

Or you can run this file directly from your IDE (assuming, that you correctly imported Maven project).

P.S. your command isn't working, because to run with `-jar` switch, the `.jar` file should have special entry in manifest that describes that class should be started by default...

P.P.S. It's better to use book's examples with Mahout 0.7, as they were tested for it.  You can use it with version 0.7 if you need, by then you need to take source code from `mahout-0.7` branch of repository with examples (link is above)

Comment: I can't get answer via your method. Please more explain. IF you can run JAVA file in CH09 in "Mahout in action", please tell me method that you use for run this files. Thnx

Comment: run eclipse, import project into it, and then use 'Run As...' command when right-click on the corresponding source file

Comment: I do this work, but not answer. This error is "Could not find or load main class ReutersToSparseVectors". Of course, i config "Run Configuration" and set main class to  "ReutersToSparseVectors" but give me this error.

Comment: `mvn exec:java` works for me without any problem - I updated my answer with precise command line

Comment: I do this with `mvn exec:java` but give me error: `BUILD FAILURE`

Comment: you never mentioned that you have build error... Did you took source code from `mahout-0.7` branch of examples? Because examples from books will not build with Mahout 0.7!

Comment: Note is here. I use code from "Mahout in action" book. Now, how i can run this code. If you can please help me. Thanks

Comment: If you want to check examples from Mahout in Action, then you need to use Mahout version 0.5! This book was written and tested for this version. Source code for examples is at https://github.com/tdunning/MiA, please, clone this version and run as per instructions in README file and my answer here. But you should use 0.5!

Comment: I need run program in ch09 in "Mahout in action" book. But [here](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA) not explain about this. If you Know this please tell me.Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I wrote in my answer how to run it with maven using `mvn exec:java` command... It works on my machine, but on your, you need to prepare data as specified in the books and only then run this example

Comment: Excuse me. Do you can run ReutersToSparseVectors in "ch09"? How set the input and output address and what type file build into addresses? I do any work for this but don't work.

Comment: You need to prepare data as described in book. name of input directory is stored in variable `inputDir`, name of output directory in `outputDir` variable.

Comment: Is `inputDir` a document file or sequence file? I understand this!

Comment: inputDir is directory with files, produced in previous steps

Comment: Hi. I wrote detailed post on how to use examples from book: http://alexott.blogspot.de/2012/07/getting-started-with-examples-from.html

Comment: You solved it using my instructions, or figured solution yourself?

Comment: If `ReutersToSparsVectors` only work on `Reuters files` or work on any of documents with different subject?